# Flask and Keras model Error ''_thread._local' object has no attribute 'value''?

Tags: python, tensorflow, flask, keras

I am using the following:
python 3.6.4

Flask = 1.1.1,

Keras = 2.3.0,

TensorFlow = 1.14.0,
I have a Flask server that gets pictures from the clients. using Keras model with a TensorFlow back-end I try to get a prediction from a pre-trained model.

I am using the following function to upload the model( as part of a class)

```
 model_path = self.conf["model_path"] // path in conf to model
 self.model = load_model(model_path)  // uploading the model
 self.model._make_predict_function()
 p_log.info("model had been upload successfully ")
```

and I use the following line for prediction:

```
cm_prediction = self.model.predict([face, reye, leye, fg])[0]
```

Until today I didn't have any problem, always got a prediction.
**now I get the following error**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\code_project\path to project", line 75, in predict
    cm_prediction = self.model.predict([face, reye, leye, fg])[0]
  File "D:\code_project\path to project", line 1462, in predict
    callbacks=callbacks)
  File "D:\code_project\predictserver\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_arrays.py", line 276, in predict_loop
    callbacks.model.stop_training = False
  File "D:\code_project\predictserver\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py", line 323, in __setattr__
    super(Network, self).__setattr__(name, value)
  File "D:\code_project\predictserver\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 1215, in __setattr__
    if not _DISABLE_TRACKING.value:
AttributeError: '_thread._local' object has no attribute 'value'
```

I have a simple Flask server running:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pre = predictor()
    # app.run(debug=True)
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=12345)
```

The model is always being uploaded.

If I am running the program **without the Flask server**, hence giving manually input, **I get a prediction**, but as soon as the **server is on** the error appears and I **stop getting a predictions**

I tried to look on the web for some similar problem but didnt found any, if someone knows what the problem and how to solve it, I will appreciate sharing it.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same situation right now. In my case, I've narrowed down the cause to some imports from another part of the package I'm working with. Did you add any new imports before this started happening?

Comment: The only thing i can think about is ```from scipy.spatial import distance as dist``` that i added before

Answer (score 23, accepted):

So after a long night,
Keras had released a new version 2.3.0 in Sep 17,19. 
As part of revision update I did, I updated all libraries, Keras among them. Since I did it the message appeared.

**After I downgraded back to Keras 2.2.5 The problem disappeared.**

Comment: After several hours of chasing imports, this solved my issue as well. Thanks!

Comment: This just saved me, thanks. Has anyone opened a bug report with Keras?

Comment: After hours of debugging different imports and failing miserably, I set Keras to 2.2.4 and TF to 1.13.1 and solved all of my errors. Seems like Keras and TF's newer versions don't work well with its older counterparts.

Answer (score 6):

If it is still relevant, I fixed this problem just by changing

```
from keras.models import Sequential

from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, LSTM
```

to

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, LSTM
```

So, no need to turn off multithreading.

Comment: This worked for me when I was working with PyQt5. I changed every import from Keras to tensorflow.keras in mtcnn library and it worked like a charm. Thanks dude !

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem when building a docker container today, which had worked perfectly before. Fixed it by downgrading Keras version to 2.2.4.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with **Keras 2.3.0**.

Another fix for those that don't want to downgrade is to set  `threaded=False` in `app.run()`.

Comment: I have the same problem what exectly is this app.run()?

Answer (score 4):

If you're having issues and are a little slow like myself, set debug=False as well

Comment: This did help me when I deployed my app on the GCP. But what is the exact problem here? This solution feels like cheating to me... Edit: My Keras is on version 2.3.1

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with my Keras models served via Flask on Google App Engine. Considering suggestions found in this thread and other places online I tried the following, none of which solved the original problem:

- Downgrading to older versions of Tensorflow and/or Keras caused my
  models fail to load.
- Using `app.run(threaded=False)` had no effect at
  all.
- Setting the graph context with
  `tensorflow.compat.v1.get_default_graph` or
  `tensorflow.python.keras.backend.get_graph` caused some other errors.

Eventually the hint found [here](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/attributeerror-thread-local-object-has-no-attribute-value/574/3) brought the solution and my app started returning valid results for all requests without any thread-related issues after I added these two lines to the code:

```
import keras.backend.tensorflow_backend as tb
tb._SYMBOLIC_SCOPE.value = True
```

Answer (score 3):

Same problem when loading multiple Keras models via Flask.
To solve the problem instead of using:

```
from keras.models import model_from_json
```

I used this:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import model_from_json
```

In the future instead of installing keras I will use tensorflow.keras.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to downgrade the package versions. If you are using `Keras` then in `Flask` server do `app.run(host=<HOST>, port=<PORT>, threaded=False)` **or** in terminal do `flask run --without-threads`. However, I will suggest to use `tensorflow.keras` instead of `keras`, so that you don't have to disable multi-threading.

Answer (score 2):

I tried all the above and here's what I found:

1. downgrading Keras didn't work, even regular non-flask calls failed to load models
2. `tb._SYMBOLIC_SCOPE.value = True` didn't work either
3. finally `threaded=False` AND `debug=False` worked.

Comment: This is an answer, admitted maybe not a very good one. Poster is saying what didn't work, and then in the third point says what did work foe them.

Answer (score 2):

No need to downgrade your library versions.
I had the same issue 
but I only tweaked the flask parameter.

`app.run("0.0.0.0", 5005, threaded=False)`

this made it finally run my code !

Let me know If you are still struggling.

Comment: Lifesaver for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Happy to help and love to be the part of this community !

Answer (score 2):

No need to downgrade `Keras` or disable multi-threading. Use `Keras` with `TensorFlow` as back-end:

```py
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
```

Answer (score 1):

please make sure you should make the value of *`threaded=False`*
Example :
for *flask* :

```
if name == 'main':
    app.run(threaded=False)
```

Comment: Don't you mean `if __name__ == '__main__'`? :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by:

1. Re-installing the latest versions of tensorflow, keras and flask (maybe order matters here...) inside the environment I used to run `app.py`
2. Importing keras from tensorflow

Current versions:

- tensorflow==2.1.0
- keras==2.3.1
- tensorflow.keras==2.2.4-tf
- flask==1.1.1

Answer (score 0):

downgrading Keras didn't work
tb._SYMBOLIC_SCOPE.value = True didn't work 
threaded=False AND debug=False didn't work

```
from keras.models import model_from_json
```

to

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import model_from_json
```

worked

Answer (score 0):

This work for me:

you must put it just before the creation of the model.

import keras.backend.tensorflow_backend as tb 
tb._SYMBOLIC_SCOPE.value = True

Answer (score 0):

None of these solutions worked for me. I switched from Flask to Bottle. Bottle is also a  fast, simple and lightweight WSGI micro web-framework for Python.

To Install Bottle

```
pip insatll bottle
```

After that, all syntaxes are same as Flask

```
from bottle import route, run, template

@route('/hello')
def index():
    return "Hello World"

run(host='localhost', port=8080)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using tensorflow 2.2 version, downgrading Keras to 2.2.5 will not help you because tensorflow 2.2 will need a keras version *greater than 2.3*.
In that case, defining the *graph* variable will do the trick for you.

so in your app.py, add these two lines of code at the top.

```
global graph
graph = tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph()
```

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading of Keras and Tensorflow versions does not work. Even setting `Threaded=False` in app.py does not solve the provlem on its own. You also need to set `debug = False`.Following works without any failure.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run(debug=False,threaded=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

For `Django` :
Use this command to run the server

```
python manage.py runserver --nothreading --noreload
```

it works perfectly fine for me