# python Flask API AttributeError AttributeError: '_thread._local' object has no attribute 'value'

Tags: python, rest, api, deep-learning, recommendation-engine

I built a recommendation engine and can get the desired output. I started an API but the problem is when I hit predict, i am unable to predict using API : I get the following error:

[image]

Please advice

Thank you all

Comment: It is not possible to provide the solution if you do not show any code, however this error message has been already discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58015489/flask-and-keras-model-error-thread-local-object-has-no-attribute-value/59531831#59531831) or [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/13353)  or couple of other forums if you search online.

Comment: Check the following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58015489/flask-and-keras-model-error-thread-local-object-has-no-attribute-value